# how to prove $ \min_{x \ne 0, ~ 1^Tx=0}\frac{x^TLx}{||x||^2}=\lambda_2(L)$

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

For a connected graph $G$ that is undirected, how to prove the following formula?
\begin{equation}
\min_{x \ne 0, ~ 1^Tx=0}\frac{x^TLx}{||x||^2}=\lambda_2(L)
\end{equation}
wherer $L$ is the Laplacian matrix of graph $G$ and $\lambda_2$ is the Fiedler eigenvalue of $L$, i.e., the second smallest nonzero eigenvalue.

Comment: It is the min-max theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you. Could you give me more details; Wiki is not enough for me :(

Comment: I have tried to write it, but there is some difficulty on the condition $1^Tx=0.$ Do we agree that the eigenvalues are ranked like this $\lambda_1 \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_n$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, and $\lambda_1=0$ in this case. I have edited my question. Specifically, the corresponding graph is undirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to *Matrix Analysis* by Roger A. Horn and Charles R. Johnson, a theorem related to **Rayleigh Quotient** is as follows (my compact version):

> **Theorem 4.2.2 (Rayleigh)**
>   Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be Hermitian, let the eigenvalues of $A$ be ordered as $\lambda_{min}(B)=\lambda_1(B) \le \lambda_2(B) \le ... \le \lambda_n(B)=\lambda_{max}(B)$, let $i_1,...,i_k$ be given integers with $1 \le i_1 < ... < i_k \le n$, let $x_{i_1},...,x_{i_k}$ be orthonormal and such that $A x_{i_p} = \lambda_{i_p} x_{i_p}$ for each $p=1,...,k$, and let $S=span\{x_{i_1},...,x_{i_k}\}$. Then 
>       \begin{equation}\label{eq34} 
>   \lambda_{i_1}=\min_{\{x:0 \ne x \in S\}} \frac{x^{*}Ax}{x^{*}x}
>  \end{equation}
>   where $x^{*}$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $x$. The minimum value is achieved if and only if $Ax=\lambda_{i_1}x$.

Then we can have the following corollary:

**Corollary**
Let $A \in M_n$ be real symmetric, let the eigenvalues of $A$ be ordered as in $\lambda_{min}(B)=\lambda_1(B) \le \lambda_2(B) \le ... \le \lambda_n(B)=\lambda_{max}(B)$, let $x_{1},...,x_{n} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be orthonormal and such that $A x_{i} = \lambda_{i} x_{i}$ for each $i=1,...,n$, and let $S=span\{x_{2},...,x_{n}\}$. Then 
    \begin{equation}\label{eq35} 
  \lambda_{2} = \min_{\{x  \in \mathbb{R}^n : x \ne 0, x_1^Tx=0\}} \frac{x^{T}Ax}{x^{T}x}
 \end{equation}
The minimum value is achieved if and only if $Ax=\lambda_{2}x$.

**Proof:**
We consider **Theorem 4.2.2** in the field of $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, it is a basic fact that there is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$, i.e. $span\{x_{1},...,x_{n} \}=\mathbb{R}^n$. Also note that $S=span\{x_{2},...,x_{n}\} = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: x_1^Tx=0\} \subseteqq \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. By letting $k=n-1$ and $i_1=2, i_2=3, ... ,i_k=n$, the remaining of the proof follows from **Theorem 4.2.2**, i.e. $ \lambda_{2} = \min_{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : 0 \ne x \in S\}} \frac{x^{T}Ax}{x^{T}x} = \min_{\{x  \in \mathbb{R}^n : x \ne 0, x_1^Tx=0\}} \frac{x^{T}Ax}{x^{T}x} . $

**Proof of my question**: Since $\xi_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \boldsymbol{1}$ is an eigenvector associated with the simple eigenvalue $\lambda_1=0$ of $L$, $\xi_1$ is automatically orthogonal to the space spanned by the rest of the eigenvectors of the (symmetric) Laplacian matrix $L$. According to the **Corollary**, it is easy to derive that
\begin{equation}
\min_{x \ne 0, ~ 1^Tx=0}\frac{x^TLx}{||x||^2}=\lambda_2(L)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

We assume $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_n.$

Let $R_L(x)=\dfrac{x^TLx}{x^Tx}$ be the Rayleigh quotient associated with hermitian matrix $L$.

Initial remark: if $P$ is invertible, we know that $P^{-1}LP$ and $L$ have the  same spectrum, thus have the same Rayleigh quotient.

The [min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) relates $\lambda_k$ to the set of $n-k+1$ dimensional subspaces in the following way:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\lambda_k=\max_U \ \{\min_x R_L(x) | \ x \in U \ \text{and} \  x \neq 0 \} \ | \ dim(U)=n-k+1 \ \}
\end{equation}

and applying it to the case $k=2$,

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\lambda_2=\max_U \ \{\min_x R_L(x) | \ x \in U \ \text{and} \  x \neq 0 \} \ | \ dim(U)=n-1 \ \}
\end{equation}

But we know that each hyperplane has an equation $x^Tv=0$ characterized by a normal vector $v$, that can be assumed with norm equal to $\sqrt{n}$ (this will be useful later).

Thus (2) can be written under the form:

\begin{equation} \tag{3}
\lambda_2=\max_{v \in S} \ \underbrace{\{\min_x R_L(x) | x^Tv=0 \ \text{and} \  x \neq 0 \}}_{int.} \ \}
\end{equation}

where $S$ is the sphere of radius $\sqrt{n}$ in  $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Here comes an essential feature that I had some difficulty to find.

Let us introduce the ([Householder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation)) symmetry matrix $H$ (that should have been denoted $H_v$) that sends $v$ to $\mathbb{1}$ (the vector with all its coordinates equal to $1$ : this is possible because $v$ and $\mathbb{1}$ have the same norm).

\begin{equation}\tag{4}
Hv=\mathbb{1} \ \ \ \iff \ \ \ v=H^{-1}\mathbb{1}
\end{equation}

As $H$ is an orthogonal transformation $H^{-1}=H^T$, it is an isometry, and in particular it is a bijection; thus the set of vectors of the form $y=Hx$ is identical to the set of vectors $x$.

This allows to transform the set "int." in (3) into:

\begin{equation}\tag{5}
\{\min_{x:=Hy} \dfrac{(Hy)^TL(Hy)}{(Hy)^T(Hy)} \  | \ (Hy)^Tv=0 \ \text{and} \  x \neq 0 \}
\end{equation}

which is equal to 
\begin{equation}\tag{6}
\{\min_{y} \dfrac{(y)^T(H^TLH) (y)}{(y)^T(H^TH)y} \  | \ (y)^T(H^Tv)=0 \ \text{and} \  x \neq 0 \}
\end{equation}

i.e, finally, because $H^T$ is the inverse of $H$,

\begin{equation}\tag{7}
\{\min_{y} \dfrac{(y)^T(L')(y)}{y^Ty} \  | \ (y)^T \mathbb{1}=0 \ \text{and} \  y \neq 0 \}
\end{equation}

where $L':=H^TLH=H^{-1}LH$ has the same spectrum as $L$ and in particular the same second eigenvalue (see initial remark upwards).

Taking the max of these sets is now reduced to ... nothing because $v$ doesn't vary any more !

Comment: I have rectified the value of the norm of $v$. Is my proof understandable ?

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have a couple of questions here. 1. $S$ should be a sphere with radius $\sqrt{n}$; 2.In (6), since it is $H^Tv=1$, then in (4) you should define the Householder transformation satisfying $H \mathbb{1}=v$. 3. Why $H$ is bijection? Is it because $H$ is invertible? 4. The reason why (3) can be transformed to (5) is only because of the bijection but has nothing to do with the isometry, am I right?

Comment: In you proof, there is nothing related to the properties of the graph corresponding to $L$. Does it mean that there are no restrictions on $L$?

Comment: For your first remark: 1. you are right, $S$ has radius $\sqrt{n}$. 2.and 3 Take into account the fact that $H$ has properties $H^t=H=H^{-1}$ because it is an **orthogonal** transformation (in particular $H^2=I$), thus $H$ is invertible because it is its own inverse. 4. It has to do with the fact that $H$ is a bijection : when $v$ "sweeps" $R^n$, $Hv$ "sweeps" $R^n$ as well.

Comment: For your second remark: yes, I dont see restrictions on the graph. The fact it is connected, for example, deals with the **first** eigenvalue.

Comment: Actually, $L$ should be a Hermitian matrix according to the min-max theorem. Therefore, the corresponding graph should be undirected. But I don't know why the graph should be connected?

Comment: please read my comment above.

Comment: It should be interesting to  make simulations of random small non connected graphs (two connected components are enough) with vertices numbered in such a way that their incidence matrices are block diagonal and see what happens, and if there is an unforeseen problem somewhere.

Comment: What is the origin of the "connectedness" condition in your issue ? Is it a personnal research work ?

Comment: I read this theorem from a research paper (Consensus problems in networks of agents with switching topology and time-delays - Olfati-Saber, Murray - 2004). It does not provide a detailed proof but with a reference to "C. Godsil and G. Royle, Algebraic Graph Theory. New York:
Springer-Verlag, 2001, vol. 207, Graduate Texts in Mathematics.
". I also looked up the theorem in the reference but could not find anything very specific. So I asked here to find whether someone could give me a hint. And yes, I may need that in my personal research work on multi-robot coordination. Are you interested?

Comment: I am interested by many parts of mathematics, in particular classical geometry and linear algebra, but also domains like signal processing, some parts of discrete mathematics (like graph theory), etc. and applied computer science (I love programing with Matlab).

Comment: I like maths, too. But I do not major in maths, and I could not say  I am very good at it. Matlab is very powerful, which is one of my favorite tools for some engineering projects. It is very nice to know you, and we can discuss some issues related to linear algebra and graph theory in the future. Anyway, thank you for your help. BTW, I think it is better if you could at least state in your answer that $L$ should be Hermitian. As for connectedness, I think I need to further research into the theorem and find out something about it. In this sense, I think the answer is not indeed completed.

Comment: I added "Hermitian" to my answer.

Comment: Another question. I think $1$ can be replaced by any vector $w$ given that $w$ and $v$ has the same norm so a Householder could be used to transform $v$ to $w$. Do you agree with me?

Comment: Yes, vector $1$ has nothing specific.

Comment: I think the proof is not correct now. $L'$ in (7) actually depends on the choice of $v$ since $H$ is not constant but depends on the choice of $v$ as well, so you can not just remove the $max$ outside.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your objection. I will have a closer look at it.

Comment: I mean $L'$ is  a function of $v$ but not a constant matrix in (7). And the $max$ operator is related to $v$.

Comment: How do you think about my comments?

Comment: I have no time at present to devote time to this question, and see if/where/why there is a  problem. Sorry if this is the case. I have devoted already a lot of time on this issue. Please let me know if you are able to make progresses in this issue.

Comment: Yes. I think I understand the theorem quite well now. Actually it is quite simple to prove it using the min-max theorem. I will write them down if I am free. I am busy preparing for next week's presentation for the time being. Sorry for costing you so much time but still, thank you for your help. If you want a quick chat, we could create a chat room and I will explain briefly to you since in this way I don't have to spend too much time on writing. :)

Comment: Fine. I have not had at all the impression to lose my time on your problem. On the contrary, I have enjoyed it! OK for chatting. Not today as you because I am in a hurry, but in the coming days. Have a nice evening.

Comment: You could check out my answer now.